# XNA SoundEffect won't stop playing

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, audio, bounding-boxes, sound-effects

For my HND I've got to re-create Frogger, and everything was going swell until I tried adding some collision detection and sound. Whenever my player intersects a vehicle, the sound file just starts playing with every game update instead of just once.

Here is my code from the update method:

```
            if (vehicles[count].bbox.Intersects(playerSprites[lives].bbox))
                playerSprites[lives].isDead = true;
        }

        if (playerSprites[lives].isDead)
        {
            deathSound.Play();
        }
```

The sound is declared as a SoundEffect, loaded as a SoundEffect, and the content processor is set to Sound Effect, and as far as I can tell, Sound Effects in XNA are only meant to be played once.
What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you are launching a sound effect **while** the player is dead, not **when** the player died. The obvious solution would be to call your soundEffect.Play here:

```
if (vehicles[count].bbox.Intersects(playerSprites[lives].bbox)){
  playerSprites[lives].isDead = true;
  deathSound.Play();
  //and also disable further intersection tests with player bbox to launch this function
  //only once. You could modify it so that its area becomes zero
}
```